# Find out if a backup ran by searching the newest file

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to write a short and simple script, that searches for a file using a specivic filter, and checks the age of that file. I want to write a short output and an error-code. This should be accessible for an NRPE-Server.

The script itself works, but I only have a problem when the file does not exist. This happens with that command:

```
newestfile=$(ls -t $path/$filter | head -1)
```

When the files exist, everything works as it should. When there nothing matches my filter, I get the output (I changed the filter to *.zip to show):

```
ls: cannot access '/backup/*.zip': No such file or directory
```

But I want to get the following output and then just exit the script with code 1:

```
there are no backups with the filter *.zip in the directory /backup
```

I am pretty sure this is a very easy problem but I just don't know whats wron. By the way, I am still "new" to bash scripts.

Here is my whole code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the variables
path=/backup
filter=*.tar.gz

# Find the newest file
newestfile=$(ls -t $path/$filter | head -1)

# check if we even have a file
if [ ! -f $newestfile ]; then
  echo "there are no backups with the filter $filter in the directory $path"
  exit 1
fi

# check how old the file is that we found
if [[ $(find "$newestfile" -mtime +1 -print) ]]; then
  echo "File $newestfile is older than 24 hours"
  exit 2
else
  echo "the file $newestfile is younger than 24 hours"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: add that on the top of your script and see if it helps: `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with your code you should also get an error message bash: no match: /backup/*.zip

**UPDATE:** Fixed the proposed solution, and the missing quotes in the original solution:

I suggest the following approach:

```
shopt -u failglob # Turn off error from globbing
pathfilter="/backup/*.tar.gz" # Quotes to avoid the wildcards to be expanded here already

# First see whether we have any matching files
files=($pathfilter)

if [[ ! -e ${#files[0]} ]]
then
  # .... No matching files
else
  # Now you can safely fetch the newest file
  # Note: This does NOT work if you have filenames
  # containing newlines
  newestfile=$(ls -tA $pathfilter | head -1)
fi
```

I don't like using `ls` for this task, but I don't see an easy way in bash to do it better.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this seems to be the best way. But I still have a Problem: Why doesn't it show me that it is empty, using: if [ -z $files ]; or if [ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]; or using the else from if (( ${#files[@]} ));... I always get the result for "array is not empty", wether files were found or not. Accessing the first element in case of non-existing according to [[ "$(declare -p files)" =~ "declare -a" ]] I still have an array with the first element being the string with $path/$filter

Comment: Testing the array size would go by `if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 ))`, but I just see that the main problem with my solution is that you get the files sorted alphabetically, not by time stamp. I need to rework it.

Comment: @25x14 : I proposed a fix

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much for your help, but I still have the issue that the check of the array still does not detect that it is ewmpty, so the code in that if-statement will not be executed. I modified your solution, and replaced the part with the newest-file and the check of the empty array with your code - in the if-statement I have the exit-code which is needed when there are no files. But when nothing matches, that code won't be reached. Its just the empty-array-check that makes problems

Comment: Updated. Of course if the pattern does not match, `files` has exactly one element, which is the pattern.

Comment: well, I think there is anything else wrong... now it always matches the IF-statement, even when I replace the path with an actual existing file instead of using wildcards